# WordPress Multisite: Super Admn lacks permissions on sub-site

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress MultiSite setup and everything works fine on the "main" site. The second site, set up in a subfolder, functions correctly except that the Super Admin account seems to lack permission to do anything. I can add a new Admin user which can post, add media, etc. But the Super Admin user can't do anything.

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the super admin as a user to the the subsite? In the Network Admin Backend you can add users to your subsite which you have probably not done and this is most likely to be the problem.

If this does not solve the problem check the rights and permissions of your network admin user with a Plugin or some custom functions: Does the network admin own the required rights (a role does not necessarily have all capabilities not even the network admin).

https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem has been resolved, I _think_ by correcting some errors in the theme's functions.php which was causing some white screens of death during other operations. Everything seems to be working normally now. Chalk this one up to carelessness I guess.